# How do I retrieve the columns of a 2D integer NumPy array that have a mean greater than a certain number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have:

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.mean(x, axis=0) > 2

output: array([False,  True])
```

the expected output for a column with a mean greater than 2:

```
[[2]
 [4]]
```

Comment: Use the boolean array as the indices of 2nd dimension. `x[:, x.mean(0) > 2]`

Answer (score 0):

In your code itself something like this can help

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a=(np.mean(x,axis=1)>2)*1
x = x*a
np.array([a[a!=0] for a in x])
```

Gives your desired output

```
array([[2],
       [4]])
```